# type(x) is list vs type(x) == list

Tags: python, types, python-object

In Python, suppose one wants to test whether the variable `x` is a reference to a list object. Is there a difference between `if type(x) is list:` and `if type(x) == list:`? This is how I understand it. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

1. `type(x) is list` tests whether the expressions `type(x)` and `list` evaluate to the same object and `type(x) == list` tests whether the two objects have equivalent (in some sense) values.
2. `type(x) == list` should evaluate to `True` as long as `x` is a list. But can `type(x)` evaluate to a different object from what `list` refers to?

What exactly does the expression `list` evaluate to? (I am new to Python, coming from C++, and still can't quite wrap my head around the notion that types are also objects.) Does `list` point to somewhere in memory? What data live there?

Comment: @j1-lee One reason is neatness, but it will also work for subclasses of the type instead of just the type itself, which you generally want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "one obvious way" to do it, that will preserve the spirit of "duck typing" is  `isinstance(x, list)`. Rather, in most cases, one's code won't be specific to a list, but could work with any sequence (or maybe it needs a mutable sequence). So the recomendation is actually:

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

... 

if isinstance(x, MutableSequence):
   ...
```

Now, going into your specific questions:

> What exactly does the expression list evaluate to? Does list point to somewhere in memory? What data live there?

`list` in Python points to a class.  A class that can be inherited, extended, etc...and thanks to a design choice of Python, the syntax for creating an instance of a class is indistinguishable from calling a function.
So, when teaching Python to novices, one could just casually mention that `list` is a "function" (I prefer not, since it is straightout false - the generic term for both functions and classes in regards to that they can be "called" and will return a result is `callable`)

Being a class, `list` does live in a specific place in memory - the "where" does not make any difference when coding in Python - but yes, there is *one* single place in memory where a class, which in Python is also an object, an instance of `type`, exists as a data structure with pointers to the various methods that one can use in a Python list.

As for:

> `type(x) is list` tests whether the expressions type(x) and list evaluate to the same object and type(x) == list tests whether the two objects have equivalent (in some sense) values.

That is correct: `is` is a special operator that unlike others cannot be overriden for any class and checks for object itentity - in the cPython implementation, it checks if both operands are at the same memory address (but keep in mind that that address, though visible through the built-in function `id`, behaves as if it is opaque from Python code). As for the "sense" in which objects are "equal" in Python: one can always override the behavior of the `==` operator for a given object, by creating the special named method `__eq__` in its class. (The same is true for each other operator - the [language data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) lists all available "magic" methods).
For lists, the implemented default comparison  automatically compares each element recursively (calling the `.__eq__` method for each item pair in both lists, if they have the same size to start with, of course)

> type(x) == list should evaluate to True as long as x is a list. But can type(x) evaluate to a different object from what list refers to?

Not if "x" is a list proper: type(x) will always evaluate to `list`. But `==` would fail if x were an instance of a subclass of `list`, or another Sequence implementation: that is why it is always better to compare classes using the builtins `isinstance` and `issubclass`.

Answer (score 2):

`is` checks exact identity, and only works if there is exactly one and only one of the `list` type. Fortunately, that's true for the `list` type (unless you've done something silly), so it usually works.

`==` test standard equality, which is equivalent to `is` for most types including `list`

Taking those together, there is no effective difference between `type(x) is list` and `type(x) == list`, but the former `is` construction better describes what's happening under the hood.

Consider avoiding use of the `type(x) is sometype` construction in favor of the `isinstance` function instead, because it will work for inherited classes too:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
isinstance(x, list)  # True

class Y(list):
    '''A class that inherits from list'''
    ...

y = Y([1, 2, 3])
isinstance(y, list)  # True
type(y) is list  # False
```

Better yet, if you really just want to see if something is list-*like*, then use `isinstance` with either `typing` or `collections.abc` like so:

```py
import collections.abc

x = [1, 2, 3]
isinstance(x, collections.abc.Iterable)  # True
isinstance(x, collections.abc.Sequence)  # True

x = set([1, 2, 3])
isinstance(x, collections.abc.Iterable)  # True
isinstance(x, collections.abc.Sequence)  # False
```

Note that lists are both `Iterable` (usable in a `for` loop) and a `Sequence` (ordered). A `set` is `Iterable` but not a `Sequence`, because you can use it in a `for` loop, but it isn't in any particular order. Use `Iterable` when you want to use in a `for` loop, or `Sequence` if it's important that the list be in a certain order.

Final note: The `dict` type is `Mapping`, but also counts as `Iterable` since you can loop over it's keys in a `for` loop.